# Differentiating between children and adults depending on AGE using Cartodb Torque wizard?

Tags: carto, torque

I'm trying to differentiate between children and adults depending on AGE, The age of these individuals are contained under the Column "palestinian_civilians" .I'm using Carto Torque wizard.Below is a little code I was using.Nothing is happening, what am I doing wrong?

```
torqueLayer.setSQL("select *,(CASE WHEN palestinian_civilians ='0' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) as palestinian_civilians_n from table");

Map {
-torque-frame-count:512;
-torque-animation-duration:30;
-torque-time-attribute:"palestinian_civilians";
-torque-aggregation-function: "round(avg(palestinian_civilians))";
-torque-resolution:2;
-torque-data-aggregation:linear;
}
#layer {
...
  marker-fill: #FF0000;
  // avg of 0 and 36
  [value > 18] { marker-fill: #0000FF; }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do something with torque cat that they recently added.

Create a column that contains the information about the group of ages that you want.

Attribute each group age to one color and then you should be good to go.